# Why does MC Haskell function result in stack overflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

I am working my way through the Haskell book and am on chapter 8. While doing the exercises I noticed something I didn't understand.

Why does this result in stack overflow

```
mc x | x>100 = x-10
     | otherwise = mc $ mc x+11
```

but this doesn't

```
mc x | x>100 = x-10
     | otherwise = mc $ mc (x+11)
```

I think it has something to do with x+11 not being evaluated in the first example but aren't expressions like that always evaluated

for example

```
Prelude> id 43+94
137
```

Comment: Hint: `id (43 + 94) == (id 43) + 94`, but that's not true for an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first expression

```
mc $ mc x+11
```

is interpreted as

```
mc ((mc x) + 11)
```

since function application takes precedence over operators.

The second expression

```
mc $ mc (x+11)
```

is interpreted as:

```
mc (mc (x+11))
```

The first indeed will never get evaluated, since if you write:

```
mc x | x > 100 = x-10
     | otherwise = mc ((mc x) + 11)
```

then you define `mc x` in terms of `mc x`. Unless that `mc x` in that expression is not evaluated, you thus will call `mc x`, when calculating `mc x`, and thus it will keep making calls.

Answer (score 4):

It's purely about operator precedence. In particular, function application takes precedence over all operators. So this:

```
mc x+11
```

is actually parsed as

```
(mc x)+11
```

and the fact that you tried to "visually" indicate the desired grouping by spacing or lack of it makes no difference. This of course is why your second version works better, since you explicitly indicated the grouping you want.

Of course, the unintended interpretation means that, for `x <= 100`, in order to evaluate `mc x` the compiler has to first evaluate `mc x`, and so on ad infinitum. Hence the eventual stack overflow.